# keras raise No gradients provided for any variable for a simple model

Tags: python, keras

I'm a newbie for keras and I just create a model to approximate a mapping from a 45-dimension vector to a 20-dimension vector.

My codes are

```
x = Input(shape=(45))
y = Dense(90)(x)
y = Dense(40)(y)
z = Dense(20)(y)

predictor = Model(x,z)
predictor.compile(optimizer='adam')
predictor.summary()

def train():
    X = []
    Y = []

    f = open('./x.txt', 'r')
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        X.append(eval(line))
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
    f = open('./y.txt', 'r')
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        Y.append(eval(line))
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
    X=np.array(X).reshape(-1,45)
    Y=np.array(Y).reshape(-1,20)
    predictor.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

And I got "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0']."

The result of `summary()` is

```
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 45)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 90)                4140      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 40)                3640      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 20)                820       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,600
Trainable params: 8,600
```

I'm not sure about where is my mistake

Comment: Add loss function here: `predictor.compile(optimizer='adam')` => `predictor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='some_loss_function')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you didn't have provided the loss function in compiler method.

So, change like this:

```
#predictor.compile(optimizer='adam')
predictor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='some_loss_function')`
```

The loss function you choose, depends on what type your problem is. If it's a regression, you can use `mse`, or it is a classification, you may use `categorical_crossentropy`.